# recursive file list check is returning duplicates

Tags: java, file, recursion, duplicates

I've made this method that goes through and finds every file inside a given directory, it then checks if it meets the requirements of a FileFilter and returns all the files that do in an array List.

```
public static ArrayList<File> listFiles(File dir, FileFilter filter) {
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    if (filter == null)
        files = listFiles(dir, files);
    else
        files = listFiles(dir, filter, files);
    return files;
}

private static ArrayList<File> listFiles(File dir, ArrayList<File> files, FileFilter filter) {
    if (!dir.isDirectory() || !dir.exists()) 
        return null;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        System.out.println(file);
        if (filter.accept(file))
            files.add(file);
        listFiles(file, filter, files);
    }
    return files;
}
```

but for some reason, it returns some files more than once...

(this is a call to the top method, which then calls the bottom method, I'm not posting the version without the fileFilter because it fails in the exact same way. If you want to know the difference then just disregard the 'if (filter.accept(file))' statement.

```
ArrayList<File> files = listFiles(new File("Notes"), new DirectoryFilter());
```

when I pass the above argument through, i get this in return

```
Notes/JavaNotes
Notes/JavaNotes/java
Notes/JavaNotes/java/io
Notes/JavaNotes/java/io/File
Notes/JavaNotes/java/io/IOException
Notes/JavaNotes/java/util
Notes/JavaNotes/java/util/ArrayList
Notes/JavaNotes/javax
Notes/JavaNotes/javax/swing
Notes/JavaNotes/javax/swing/JFrame
Notes/JavaNotes
Notes/JavaNotes/java
Notes/JavaNotes/java/io
Notes/JavaNotes/java/io/File
```

The last four files are duplicates of the first four files. it is failing predictably too, only the first 4 line of files is added twice (so if there were only 2 files in a line before that directory hit an end then only 2 files would be duplicated).

the directoryFilter is the reason why there is no actual .txt files in the results.

Comment: Add the listFiles method which takes 3 parameters to your post please.

Comment: alright I added the blocks of code that could be useful.

Comment: What you've pasted is wrought with errors. The method signatures don't match your calls, and it looks like you're way over complicating things. Clean up your code and post working examples here, or you'll get no help...

Comment: only error I found in what I pasted here was a mismatched argument, everything was just imports and name changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me (after fixing the errors and some cleanup).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.err.println(listFiles(new File(args[0]), new FileFilter() {   
            @Override public boolean accept(File pathname) { 
                return true;
            }
         }));
    }

    public static ArrayList<File> listFiles(File dir, FileFilter filter) {
         ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
         listFiles(dir, files, filter);
         return files;
    }

    private static void listFiles(File dir, ArrayList<File> files, FileFilter filter) {
        if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
             return;
        }
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (filter.accept(file)) {
                 files.add(file);
            }
            listFiles(file, files, filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain this to make it a little bit more clear? I think I'm missing the difference and why that difference works for you...

Comment: It's pretty much your code... I changed the 3 arg `listFiles` method to return `void` cause the file list is already passed as a parameter. The 'dir.exists` check to end the recursion seemed redundant --- if it is a directory, it must also exist. I added curly braces to make it clearer what the blocks in the `if` statements are. I added `import` statements and a main method so that I can run the code. I added a filter that accepts all files, cause your code cannot handle a `null` filter. Do you have any concrete questions about the code?

Comment: Yea When I copied and pasted your code into my IDE it worked but when I made the changes to my code it didn't... I'm gonna fool around with it a little more to see if I can find why, and if I can't I'll update the OP...  BTW before you changed my code did you have the same problem I did?

Comment: Oh never mind lol... The problem I was getting was from another method that was written incorrectly that I called directly after the above method... now I feel kinda dumb. It looks like the code in the OP works just fine... But mark your answer as correct anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @Totalllyrandomguy That's one of the reasons why people ask for a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)